# using xlsx with R jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install and use the xlsx lackage in R in a Jupyter notebook on a Mac.

```
install.packages("xlsx")
```

seems to run OK but

```
library("xlsx")
```

results in:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'xlsx':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Traceback:

1. library("xlsx")
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

I tried sudo R CMD javareconf which resulted in:

Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 13.0.2
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13-openj9.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/default -ljvm
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13-openj9.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13-openj9.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13-openj9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/default -ljvm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation

JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13-openj9.jdk/Contents/Home
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/default
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/default -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is a pretty common error. You need to install the latest version of Java, and then `install.packages('rJava')`. On a mac I use `brew install` to make java play nice. the bottom line is that that package is a wrapper around rJava and rJava requires java to run

Comment: Just a tip: If you are only installing `xlsx` to work with `.xlsx` files (not `.xls') consider `openxlsx` which gets rid of the java dependency. I had great success with using it for working with excel files (albeit only the newer`xlsx` format is supported)

Comment: OK. I used the Java control panel to get the latest version of Java. (v8 update 241). I then did as you suggested: install.packages('rJava') and I redid library("xlsx) and got the same error

Comment: Did as you suggested, installed openxlsx and it works fine. I don't know why xlsx wouldn't load but I can now write xlsx files. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

library(readxl)

df<- read_xlsx(path,sheet= sheet number) #use this if you want to import xlsx

df<- read_xls(path,sheet= sheet number) #use this if you want to import xls